# How do I port multiple routers to one target file?

Tags: informatica

I have a mapping in Informatica Developer where it was originally flowing from a router to two target tables that are used to create to kinds of out files.    if The Line_Item_id is 555 or 556, it routes to one target, everything else goes to the other target. The problem is now, I need for the the line items to be separated but go to the same target because another column 'product_code' should be different hard coded values depending on the 555 or 556 line_item_id and I'm not sure how to do that.  (So Line_item 555 product code = PC555 and Line_item 556 = PC556)

Comment: Can't you just use an Expression transformation with `DECODE(line_item_id, '555', 'PC555', '556', 'PC556')`?

Answer (score 0):

Best: remove the router and use Expression Transformation to calculate the values of your column (just as Samik indicated in the comment).

Alternatively: use Union Transformation to bring the routed pipelines together.